# Data is getting stored as array of JSON object and not just JSON object in Postgres using TypeORM

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM in my NodeJS function. I have Postgres database where the table column **emp_data** is of type JSON and not JSON[]. But data is getting stored **in the form of array of objects and not just object itself**.

Here is my logic of passing data :-

```
      let emp1 = [{
        "EmployeeID": "1391",
        "FirstName": "Vinod",
        "LastName": "Kumar",
      }];
      let emp2 = [{
        "EmployeeID": "0827",
        "FirstName": "Vijay",
        "LastName": "Kumar",
      }];

     const res = await dbConn
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .insert()
        .into(IntegrationData)
        .values(
          { empId: 1391, empData: emp1, integrationName: 'workday'},
          { empId: 0827, empData: emp2, integrationName: 'workday'},
        )
        .execute();
```

Entity:-

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity } from "typeorm";

@Entity({ name: "integration_data" })
export class IntegrationData extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "bigint" })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: "bigint", name: "emp_id" })
  empId: number;

  @Column({ type: "json", name: "emp_data" })
  empData: any;

  @Column({ name: "integration_name" })
  integrationName: string;
}
```

Refer attached screenshot. Data is being stored in the column **emp_data** as array of object.
[image]

I understand that I'm passing emp1 and emp2 as an array of object but the problem is if I convert this emp1 or emp2 to just object then I get compatible issue error (refer attached screenshot).

[image]

Please help me in storing the data as JSON object and not as array of JSON object. Thanks

Comment: Did you try //@ts-ignore just to make sure that your syntax is working for injecting data into database but that compiler is misreading something with your typings ?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to set the type annotation of `empData` to `unknown`.

Or...

You could set the `empData` property to `string` and use `JSON.stringify` to save a JSON directly.

```js
let emp1 = {
  "EmployeeID": "1391",
  "FirstName": "Vinod",
  "LastName": "Kumar",
};

// ...

const insert = db.CreateQueryBuilder() 
  // ...
  .values({ empDate: JSON.stringify(emp1) })
  // ...
```

Or..

You could create an interface to have properly type checking if you know that the object shape won't change often.

```js
interface EmployeeData {
  EmployeeID: string;
  FirstName: string;
  LastName: string;
}

export class IntegrationData extends BaseEntity {
  // ...

  /* 
    Interfaces doesn't exists in runtime, so object shape isn't guaranteed.
  */
  @Column({ type: "json", name: "emp_data" })
  empData: EmployeeData;

  // ...
}
```